# Hiding Rest Service Url in Javascript

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, web-service, arcgis-rest-api

While users using my application, they can view resource from browser and see my arcgis rest service URLs. So If I use token based security, security token can view.
Can I hide this from users?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know ArcGIS very well, a possible solution is using an http proxy: your client sends the requests to a proxy which add the token in the url. With this solution, the clients doesn't know about the token

```
client --> (/rest/resource) --> | PROXY | --> (/rest/resource?token=xxx) --> arcgis
```

Some documentation can be found

- [Working with token authentication](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/ags_security.htm)
- [Using the proxy page](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisserver/apis/javascript/arcgis/help/jshelp_start.htm#jshelp/ags_proxy.htm)

Another solution (easier, but I don't know if is supported by arcgis) is put the token not in the url but in the header or as a cookie. It won't be visible in the url anymore, it's easier, but it could be seen using any of the developer tools that are shipped with almost all browser...